# Can I Run Dash app (Flask app) on a Drupal Apache Server?

Tags: apache, server, drupal, plotly-dash

The title is basically my question. Below is some background info.

I am trying to create an interactive visualization dashboard consisting of multiple graphs. I have a MongoDB database, which is updated once a day automatically.

I am familiar with Python, HTML, CSS but I am not an expert in Drupal and PHP, so I'm trying to use Python to make the visualization. Specifically, I am using Dash Plotly with HTML  tag to paste it on the webpage. Right now the Dash app is deployed under my local computer's IP address running in the terminal.

Now I want to take this app live on the server so that I don't have to keep my computer on. Is it safe to deploy and run a Dash app (or a Flask app, they are basically the same) via Apache on my Drupal web server?

Drupal Info:
Drupal Version: 9.1.2
Web Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
PHP Version: 7.4.3

Server Info:
Two CPUs: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz
RAM: 4GB

I don't have much server knowledge and I can't find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by simply deploying the dash app on Apache server, then using HTML iframe tag to embed to the specific webpage on drupal.